# Camel - How to configure redeliver only for HTTP Code 500 series

Tags: java, apache-camel, esb, fuseesb, apache-camel-cdi

I have configured the re delivery related properties as follows. In fact, I wanted to retry only for HTTP Code 500x series. But I see that onException() takes only exception type. How to achieve this? My application is spring boot & camel based.

```
errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler().maximumRedeliveries(3).redeliveryDelay(5000).logRetryAttempted(true).logExhausted(true));

onException().retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
```

Camel 2.23 is the version I am using(As per the comment).

Answer (score 0):

Need more information, how you get resp code.
if you get response from camel route you can add condition in route:

```
.choice().when().simple("header.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE >= 500").errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler().maximumRedeliveries(3).redeliveryDelay(5000).logRetryAttempted(true).logExhausted(true)).end();
```

Comment: Hi Anatoly, Thanks for the reply. Here .errorHandler does not seem to be available after simple() expression.

This is what I am trying to do.

from("C:/IN")
.process(new RequestMessageProcessor())
.to("http://localhost:8090/getItem")
.process(new ResponseMessageProcessor())
.to("C:/OUT"))